# CSV - Split multiple-line cell into multiple cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, split

I’m currently doing some big data work.  I have an issue in a .CSV where I need to split a multiple-line single-celled chunk of text, into individual cells.  The below table shows the desired output.  Currently, all of the 'ingredients' are in the same cell, with each ingredient on its own new line (Stack Overflow wouldn't allow me to create new lines in the same cell).

I need to write a script to split this single cell of ingredients into the below output, using each new line in the cell as a delimiter.  The real use case I'm using this for is much more complex - over 200 'items', and anywhere between 50-150 'ingredients' per 'item'.  I'm currently doing this manually in excel with a series of text to columns & transpose pastes, but it takes approximately 2-2.5 full work days to do.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WIsQwPok-EXx5sXra7z_f4qe10u8CYkP/view?usp=sharing) to data

Code below

| Item | Ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| Coffee | Coffee beans |
|  | Milk |
|  | Sugar |
|  | Water |

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'd:\Python\menu.csv', delimiter=';', header=None)
headers = ["Item", "Ingredients"]
df.columns = headers
df["Ingredients"]=df["Ingredients"].str.split("\n")
df = df.explode("Ingredients").reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv(r"D:\Python\output.csv")
```

Comment: Could you show what your data looks like as text? It's hard to follow with the table.

Comment: Edited - Link to .csv file in question.  I need each of the software items in the .csv to be split into individual cells, but can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with Python's standard **csv**[^1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) [^2](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/618d3348855a31b7dd90e221f4e0dba7) module:

```py
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w', newline=''))

reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv', newline=''))

writer.writerow(next(reader))  # copy header

for row in reader:
    item  = row[0]
    ingredients = row[1].split('\n')

    first_ingredient = ingredients[0]

    writer.writerow([item, first_ingredient])

    for ingredient in ingredients[1:]:
        writer.writerow([None, ingredient])  # None for a blank cell (under the item)
```

Given your small sample, I get this:

| Item | Ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| Coffee | Coffee beans |
|  | Milk |
|  | Sugar |
|  | Water |

Comment: You're a god...

Comment: Is there a way for me to specify which column the 'ingredients' write to?  There are some other columns in the .csv that I deleted for simplicity's sake, but they're functioning fine with the script.  Currently, the 'ingredients' are writing to the 2nd column, but I need them to write to the 4th.

Comment: @CunnyFunt, yes change `row[1]` to `row[3]`, and a two more `None`'s to "pad out" the new rows, `...writerow([None, None, None, ingredient])`.

Comment: Buy yourself a beer for me @Zach Young

Comment: @CunnyFunt, I'll do that, thanks. I'm really hoping you understand how reading and writing the rows works... it's such a fundamental thing to working with CSVs. I'm also curious if my guide (the second link) helps. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using your code and linked data change delimeter to a comma like below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Inventory.csv', delimiter=',')
df["Software"]=df["Software"].str.split("\n")
df = df.explode("Software").reset_index(drop=True)

# Remove rows having empty string under Software column.
df = df[df['Software'].astype(bool)]

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv("out_Inventory.csv")

print(df.to_string())
```

##### Output

```
        Hostname                                                                                                                Software
0    ServerName1        Windows Driver Package - Amazon Inc. (AWSNVMe) SCSIAdapter  (08/27/2019 1.3.2.53)  [version 08/27/2019 1.3.2.53]
1    ServerName1                                                                               Airlock Digital Client  [version 4.7.1.0]
2    ServerName1                                                                 AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  [version 1.1.2106.32]
3    ServerName1                                                                                   BlueStripe Collector  [version 8.0.3]
...
```